# Extracting value of an element using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, getattribute

I'm using Python 3 and I need help with extracting the value of an element in a HTML code. The relevant part of the webpage code looks like this:

```
<span class="ng-isolate-scope" star-rating="4.61" size="22">
```

I'm currently using Selenium and the get_attribute function, but I have not been able to extract the 4.61 value. Since I have to loop over several webpages, the relevant part of my code looks like this:

```
stars=[]
i=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@star-rating]")
for y in i:
    temp=str(y.get_attribute("value"))
    stars.append(temp)
```

but it is not working as I would expect. Could you help me in terms of what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the `star-rating` attribute instead of a `value`:

```
temp = y.get_attribute("star-rating"))
```

Note that you don't have to call `str()` on the result of `get_attribute()` - you'll get the attribute value as a string.

You can also improve the code and collect the ratings in a single line using a list comprehension:

```
stars = [elm.get_attribute("star-rating") 
         for elm in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@star-rating]")]
```

And, if you need the ratings as floats, call `float()`:

```
stars = [float(elm.get_attribute("star-rating")) 
         for elm in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@star-rating]")]
```

---

And, it would be a little bit more concise with a [CSS selector](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_elements_by_css_selector):

```
stars = [float(elm.get_attribute("star-rating")) 
         for elm in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("[star-rating]")]
```

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thanks a lot @alecxe ! And thanks for the suggestions on coding, they're very much appreciated.